# Why is "it's nice to hearing from you" wrong?

Tags: grammar, verbs, gerunds

why don't we say:

> it is nice to hearing from you

is it because **nice** does not come from a verb, like confessed to, opposed to, close to, in the expression such as I am opposed to drinking, or I am confessed to lying and I am close to having none

Answer (score 17):

It's because if whatever follows constructions like **it is nice**, **it is good**, **it is bad** et cetera is a verb, it must either be in its infinitive form (infinitives are formed by preceding [**the bare infinitive**](https://www.englishgrammar.org/bare-infinitive-2/) of a verb with the particle *to*) or in its gerund form (you can even refer to it as a present participle or more generically as an "ing" form since in this particular case it really makes no practical difference what you call it). It's an either/or situation and there is nothing in between. That's why. *hearing* is not the infinitive of *hear*. It's the gerund form of *hear*. The infinitive of *hear* is *to hear*. So, it should be either *hear* with the *to* which turns it into an infinitive as required or *hearing* without the *to*:

> It is nice **to hear** from you.
>
> It is nice **hearing** from you.

Long story short, *to* in this case is not a preposition like it is in *I am opposed to drinking*. It's something called [**an infinitive marker**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/infinitive-marker) whose sole purpose is to indicate that the verb is being used in its infinitive form. *to* plays the same role in forming infinitives as *ing* in forming gerunds. The upshot of this all is that phrases like *to hearing* where *to* is an infinitive maker are just grammatically impossible.

Comment: In OP's construction, they're missing the infinitive `be` for the construction `to be [gerund]` (I think gerund) - "It is nice to be hearing from you", which also works.

Comment: @BruceWayne But that has a different meaning, since it is present progressive tense, so it implies that the action of hearing is still ongoing, whereas "It's nice to hear from you" often ends a conversation. Also, in that case, "hearing" is a present participle rather than a gerund. http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/tenses/present_progressive.htm

Answer (score 4):

Not only did the adjectives derive from verbs and followed by “to” must be followed by a gerund, but there are adjectives (derived from other words) and they still apply to this matter that gerund come after them.

And, I think, those adjectives that come with specifically certain verbs to forms “combined adjectives with prepositions” must be memorized.  [image: Adjectives + prepositions]

> - I am  **allergic** to **eating** apple.
> - English language learners site is very **beneficial** to **improving** your understanding of English.
> - My body health system is **immune** to **getting** infected by different diseases.

- Look, in all these examples the adjectives aren’t derived from verbs, but they are still followed by (to + gerund)

You can look into this link to see many of them. [the source](https://www.bedavaingilizce.com/prepositions/adj_pre.htm)

Comment: why is" nice to " in this list?.We say" it was nice to hear from you"  It is not followed by a gerund

Comment: @user5577 It's probably there because you can say "He was nice **to me**", in which case *to* is a preposition and not an infinitive marker.  Unfortunately, lists like this can be a bit misleading at times.